# Vaadin request processing per http session

Tags: browser, vaadin, httpsession

Am using Vaadin 6.8. Though the below link describes how Vaadin supports multiple browser tab,

https://vaadin.com/web/joonas/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Supporting%20Multible%20Tabs

Tabs of same browser will be using same http session and hence same application instance. However, tabs use different window objects there by giving an illusion of multi tab support.

But, Vaadin locks the application instance while processing the httprequests (specially updateUIDL calls). All http requests for a given session are processes serially. 
Until tab1 request is processed completely, tab2 request will not be processed.

So, a busy loading icon is shown on both tabs.

AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest() locks the application object.

**Anyone has a workaround for this issue?** or 
**Is there anyway to force vaadin to use new http session for each tab or pop up?**

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to solve this.
Vaadin 7 of course solves all this for you (So we are currently in the process of upgrading to Vaadin 7)

Comment: Thanks for a quick response Andre. I agree, but currently I cannot upgrade to vaadin 7. Was thinking if there were any work around for the issue.